# Set up vim, latex for AGU template

Tags: compiling, eps, vim, agutex

On a Mac, I have been using vim-latex for a while and had set it up a while ago to output pdfs via the `:ll` command in vim (using pdflatex if I'm correct) and viewing the output via the `:lv` command (using skim which refreshes automatically on change). This was very convenient for me to work with. Important detail: all my external figures were pdf.

However hopefully I will soon publish some article(s) in an AGU journal, and started working with their template. They require eps format figures, which is not an issue in itself. But now obviously they do not render through the (probable) pdflatex compiling rule that I have been using so far.

I would like to keep the same workflow capability (view output right away by typing `:lv` or a single command, and have the output refresh on change) while working with the AGU template, and the required eps figures. Which means (I think) I need to either set the right compilation rule, or to switch to another way of working. The vim-latex documentation for setting those compiling rules is quite complicated in my opinion, so any advice would be most welcome!

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Comment: I should also say, an alternative workflow could be to use [`epstopdf`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf-pkg) package and sticking with `pdflatex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding this in my .vimrc so that the compiling rule is dvi -> ps -> pdf and I have no issues with eps figures now :

```
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = 'pdf'
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'ps2pdf $*.ps'
let g:Tex_CompileRule_dvi = 'latex --interaction=nonstopmode $*'
let g:Tex_CompileRule_ps = 'dvips -Ppdf -o $*.ps $*.dvi'
let g:Tex_FormatDependency_pdf = 'dvi,ps,pdf'
```